# Maximum number of activewidth object allowed

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

My program runs fine with limited data but when I put in all four databases activewidth won't work.

Database 1 has 29990 entries.
Database 2 has around 27000 entries.
Database 3 has roughly 17000 entries.
Database 4 has 430 entries.

Each database, grouped by its kind and includes business type, name, address, city, state, phone number, longitude, latitude, sales tax info, and daily hours of operation.

In total 12.1Mb of data.

With database 1 only in the program it works fine and I can scroll over a point on the map and activewidth will increase the size of the dot and the program will bring up the underlying data on the left hand side of the screen just like it is suppose to do.

Now that I have added in all four maps and can click them on and off separately, with only #1 turned on activewidth won't work and the underlying data won't show on the left.  The points on the map are there and I can click through all four checkbuttons and turn on and off the points.  I currently don't have the code in yet for the underlying data on database 2-4, just the ability to turn them on and off.  Only activewidth isn't working now that I've got it so I can view the points for all 4 databases.

I decided to try commenting out all code for databases 2-4 and see what would happen and it went back to working fine again.  Then I went and added in database 2 back into the mix and it went back to not working again.  Then I tried database 2 only and it was activewidthing fine as long as database 1 was commented out.  With database 1 active the activewidth was very slow to work/not working at all.

Is there a feasible maximum number of entries I can use.  Hopefully not because I still have several more databases to get finished off and added into the program that will take the total number of entries up over 100K before all is said and done.

Nothing else makes sense since I'm just changing self.alocation to self.blocation, when I go to add in database 2-4.  I'm just changing the identifier to show which database is being worked with and copying the rest of the code over between routines since everything is the same...just different business separated into appropriately grouped databases.  It seems it's in the amount of data that is being used and not in the anything doing with the way the program is written.

I figured by splitting up the files, not only for my benefit but also to make the files smaller it would help alleviate the problem but so far it hasn't.  Is there any other way to work around data overload?

```
self.alocation = []
for x in range(0, len(self.atype)):
    pix1x = round((float(self.along[x])+(-self.longitudecenter+(self.p/2)))/(self.p/714),0)
    pix1y = round((((self.p/2) + self.latitudecenter-(float(self.alat[x])))/(self.p/714)),0)
    z = self.canvas.create_line(pix1x, pix1y, pix1x+4, pix1y+4, activewidth="10.0", fill = '', width = 5)
    self.alocation.append((z,x))
```

Comment: What is an "activewidth"? Are you using some library other than just Tkinter? There seem to be some very important details missing from your question.

Comment: Activewidth changes the size of the point when you scroll over a point with the mouse.  Standard tkinter.

Comment: Just added in the code that I am using to set the dot on the screen which shows activewidth in use.